# Emacs using Common Lisp with cl-lib.el

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, elisp

I have been using ELISP for a while and now I have decided to use Common Lisp using `cl-lib.el` extension for Emacs. The question is does `cl-lib.el` provide a complete CLISP extension for Emacs or it partially supports CLISP? The other question, if I include `cl-lib.el` in one package (I have multiple packages), does that mean the `cl-lib.el` will also be applied to all other packages? For example, if I have:

```
(load "~/elisp/file1.el") ; (require 'cl-lib.el)
(load "~/elisp/file2.el") ; does it automatically use cl-lib.el or not?
```

Comment: `cl-lib.el` is a subset of `cl.el`. It was created because some people wanted to use some of the more commonly used parts of `cl.el`, without needing to load all of `cl.el` at runtime.

Comment: If you want to load the CL macros at byte-compile time, and you do not need any CL functions at runtime, then you need not load either `cl-lib.el` or `cl.el` at runtime - just `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))` or `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl-lib))`

Comment: Side note: CLISP is the name of a specific Common Lisp compiler, it's not the name of the language.

Comment: @Drew: `cl-lib` is not really a subset of `cl`.  It's more like the successor of `cl`, with the main difference being the naming (all definitions have a name that starts with the `cl-` prefix).  A few parts of `cl` have been moved to core when `cl-lib` was introduced (mostly `setf`), and some rare elements were dropped altogether, and others rare elements were added as well, but overall, they pretty much have the same contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No; neither `cl-lib.el` nor `cl.el` is equivalent to Common Lisp. Not at all.
2. Once a library has been loaded, it is loaded. If you load `file1` and it loads `cl-lib`, then when you later load `file2`, `cl-lib` has already been loaded. All that matters is the order of loading.

Comment: I was hoping to hear something else! I hope one day we have a complete Emacs written in Common Lisp.

Comment: Me too. ;-)  I doubt it will ever come, but I think Common Lisp would be great for Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

If you were hoping that `cl` / `cl-lib` would provide more of Common Lisp than they do, you may be interested in https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsCommonLisp

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I already checked it out. It's not very clear on cl-lib can do or cannot do.